# Why am I missing 2% of my ram

Tags: memory, ram

I am running `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo` to determine the RAM installed on a system, however instead of reporting a number corresponding to an even number of GiB, it is slightly off.

I.e. on my 64 GiB system I get a report of 65854272 kiB, which is equivalent to 62.8 GiB. Where did my 1.2 GiB go? Why does the tool not display them to me?

`free -b` reports 67434774528 which is in line with the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MemTotal: Total usable RAM in kilobytes (i.e. physical memory minus a few reserved bytes and the kernel binary code)

Source: [Torvalds linux github repro (linux/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)

Check BIOS reserved memory:

```
dmesg | grep BIOS | grep reserved
```

Comment: Is the Bios reserved memory given in words (of 4 Bytes), rather than Bytes? Otherwise it does not add up to 1.2 GB.

Comment: Also note that 1 GB != 1 GiB.